# Can WhatsApp video calls be restored/reviewed?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

In WhatsApp, one can view the detail of video call history by tapping the entry on it.

[image]

The video calls have a volume on the device, so can they be restored and reviewed?

Answer (score 1):

**No, WhatsApp video calls can't be restored and reviewed.** It's not stored anywhere locally on the phone or remotely on the internet.

The size shown here is the total data transferred through the internet while on the video call. It's basically the usage of network data, *mostly for data usage auditing/monitoring on a limited internet plan.*

There are some 3rd-party apps that can record WhatsApp video calls locally on the phone, but WhatsApp doesn't have a feature to record both phone and video calls natively.